# Misma entidad distintas tablas NestJs

Tags: sql, api, nestjs

Estoy iniciando con APIs, trabajando con NestJS, tengo una entidad control con 3 columnas, id, temp, date. El tema es que distintos controles deberian guardar datos en distintas tablas, por ejemplo el control a2323 en la tabla idem nombre, el control a2324 en la tabla idem nombre y asi sucesivamente para ller y guardar registros. Como maneja esto este entorno. Con php era tan facil como mandar un item en el control con el nombre del mismo y usar en la query, pero aca no se como manejarlo.

Sera que debo implementar un repositorio o Servicio generico?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: La idea es recibir distintos datos a entidades similares pero que se guardan en distintas tablas y usar la misma entidad en la api ya que la entidad tiene siempre el mismo formato pero se guardan en tablas distintas, cuyo nombre tambien viene en los datos.